# Varnish (Bug or incorrect config) If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since always blank

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

i'm using version 3.0.2 windows pre-compiled version with cygwin, and this may be related to the issue.

I am trying to capture the

- If-None-Match
- If-Modified-Since

headers

The headers are being sent by the browser, I can see in developer tools that these are being sent to Varnish, but I am unable to pull the value in varnish.

I have tried

- Getting the values at the top of vcl_recv and setting new headers (in case the values were being overidden)
- I have tried both

  - req.http.If-None-Match and req.http.If-Modified-Since
  - bereq.http.If-None-Match and bereq.http.If-Modified-Since

should these work? I am trying to access the value in vcl_fetch

Anyone having a similar issue?

Comment: It seems that you cannot get the genuine

    If-Modified-Since
    If-None-Match

in vcl_recv or vcl_fetch, but if I move the code to vcl_deliver it all works correctly.

I don't know if this is a bug or intentional but seems to solve my issue.

Comment: If anyone knows how to access the headers in recv or fetch i would still be very interested to know

Answer (score 0):

Both headers should be accessible in vcl_fetch.  You should be able to confirm this with a minimal VCL file which simply echoes those those two headers back to the client as response headers.

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.http.X-If-Modified-Since = req.http.If-Modified-Since;
    set beresp.http.X-If-None-Match = req.http.If-None-Match;
}
```

If this does not work for you, please post the "varnishlog" output, preferably for an uncached response.  Are there any other HTTP proxies between the browser and varnish?

I should note that varnish *does* filter out both headers when making backend requests, so if you need to access those headers from application code, you will need to copy them in vcl_recv.